# Fix my script? How can I automatically create events in google calendar using dates from google sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-calendar, worksheet-function

I read that it is possible to link a google sheet to google calendar, so dates can be used to create events in the calendar. I used script I found around about, but absolutely nothing happens. Can anybody see where I have gone wrong? (Note - I have hidden contents of columns A and B, but title of column D refuses to be imported)

```
//function to retrieve data from Sheet and add first reports to Calendar
function simpleSheetsToCalendar() {

  //get spreadsheet
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Report1');

  //get the data from Google Sheet
  var data = sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow(),2,2,12).getValues();

  //create variables
  var title = data[0][0];
  var eventLoca=data[0][1];
  var eventDesc = data[0][2];
  var eventDate =[0][3];

  //get calendar
  var masterCal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById('diilmyangon@gmail.com');

  //add to calendar
  masterCal.createAllDayEvent(title, location, description,date)

}
```

[image]

Not sure if this is part of the problem, but I imported a range from the first sheet in my doc, using this formula `=query(IMPORTRANGE("<https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1uxIkcjOTxFAd25Ukzji3VJKoFbAKybuFXfHlBzaGDWc/edit#gid=1385200762>","Master!A3:y"),"select Col2, Col3, Col12, Col13",0)`

But for some reason the title cell of column 13 does not import. I have another post on that.

[image]

Comment: Welcome. The green area on your screenshots makes harder to see what you want to show. Please edit your screenshots. By the way, the problem with you formula could be that the url is enclose between `<` and `>`, remove these chararacters. Regarding your function, the arguments  in `masterCal.createAllDayEvent(title, location, description,date)` have not being declared

Answer (score 0):

One problem with you formula is that the url is enclosed between `<` and `>`, remove these characters.

Regarding your function, the arguments in `masterCal.createAllDayEvent(title, location, description,date)` have not being declared.

You could save a lot of time while writing your scripts / fixing them by following the recommendations of https://developers.google.com/apps-script/troubleshooting like

- Log execution info by using Logger or console
- Using the built-in debugger
- Reading the execution transcript